# Função em jquery botão desabilitado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para uma `div` ser exibida quando um botão estiver desabilitado, e quando estiver habilitado quero que essa `div` fique oculta

```
 $(document).on('ready', '#btn-cadastra-atividade', function () 
    { 
    $this = $(this)
    if($this.attr('disabled') === true)
    { 
       $('#erroAtividade').show(); 
    }
    else
    {   
    $('#erroAtividade').hide(); 
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta comparar se o elemento possui o atributo `'disabled'`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.botao', function () { 
   $this = $(this)
   if($this.attr('disabled') === true)
   { 
      $('div').show(); 
   }else
   {   
      $('div').hide(); 
   }
});
```

Caso queira disparar isto em outro evento, basta qual será o trigger:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $this = $('.botao');
   $this.each(function() {
      
 console.log('Disabled:' + $(this).prop('disabled')+' - ' + $(this).text())
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div'>div</div>
<button class='botao' disabled>Botão desabilitado X</button>
<button class='botao'>Botão Y</button>
```

Comment: Eu adaptei mas não funcionou, coloquei o código na pergunta

Comment: Mas o que exatamente você quer fazer com o botão ? pra disparar o evento 'onready', você precisa indicar o documento, e depois o evento, no caso você fez certo, mas o 'ready' não irá disparar, você precisa de um mutation ou equivalente, algo como:

 $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '#btn-cadastra-atividade', function () 

Porém esse evento está descontinuado, precisaria verificar os mutation observers, mas eu nunca usei pra saber te dizer qual a diferença.

Comment: Não teria nenhuma ação direta no botão, só queria que a função escutasse  quando esse botão estivesse desabilitado exibir a div, e quando habilitado, ocultasse a mesma div

Comment: Então esse evento 'DOMNodeInserted' é pra funcionar, mas você vai precisar encontrar o modo atualizado equivalente pra ele, pois esse logo logo não vai funcionar mais.

Comment: De uma olhada no snnipet que adicionei a resposta.

Comment: Não funcionou :( ele exibiu o alert mas não fez a ação da div

Comment: Ele da sim, você precisa adicionar o 'disabled' ao botão, se tiver o attr disabled, ele mostra a div, se não tiver o attr disabled a div fica oculta. 
No exemplo ele está sem o disabled, no caso, esconde a div, se você adicionar 'disabled' ao button, a div é exibida.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo onde mostra os dois status do botão:

```js
function divOnButton() {
  if ($('#btn1').prop('disabled')) {
    $('#div1').show();
  } else {
    $('#div1').hide();
  }
}

function statusOnButton() {
  $('#btn1').prop('disabled', !$('#btn1').prop('disabled'));
  divOnButton()
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  divOnButton();
  $("#btnStatus").click(function() {
    statusOnButton();
  });
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#conteudo {
  height:18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Como faço para uma div ser exibida quando um botão estiver desabilitado, e quando estiver habilitado quero que essa div fique oculta-->
<div id="conteudo">
  <div id="div1">
    Div Habilitada
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="btn1" disabled>Botão</button>

<br /><br />
<br /><br />

<button id="btnStatus">Mudar Status Botão</button>
```